# Stopping Gitlab from Skipping Git repository setup

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

i am not sure why my gitlab is skipping Git repository setup as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsEA0.png)

is there any way for me to ensure that a git repository is always set up when i run a pipeline in gitlab? in what situation would gitlab skip the setting up of a git repository?

Answer (score 1):

By default, the GitLab runner should retrieve the repository and configure the workspace in pipeline jobs according to its configured git strategy. This behavior can be controlled in two primary ways:

- The [default git strategy setting](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/settings.html#choose-the-default-git-strategy)
- The [`GIT_*`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/configure_runners.html#configure-runner-behavior-with-variables) environment variables that control the runner's behavior -- most importantly the `GIT_STRATEGY`, `GIT_CHECKOUT`, and `GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY` variables

For example, if the `GIT_STRATEGY` variable (or the project setting default) is set to `none` then you will see these messages like "Skipping Git repository setup".

To ensure the repository is setup as you expect in jobs, ensure:

1. The [project setting](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/settings.html#choose-the-default-git-strategy) is correct (set to `clone` or `fetch`)
2. That the `GIT_STRATEGY` variable is either unset or explicitly set to `clone` or `fetch`
3. That the `GIT_CHECKOUT` variable is either unset or explicitly set to `true`
4. If your project uses git submodules, that an appropriate value is used for the `GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY` variable

Keep in mind that there are several places where variables can be set (CI yaml files, project settings, group settings, instance settings, runner settings, etc.) and the [precedence of those variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#cicd-variable-precedence) is important to consider as well.

---

It is worth noting that, in some cases, it may be normal to disable GitLab's normal clone/checkout process. For example, when a GitLab project is used as external CI for a project located somewhere else or when using a custom runner/executor/script that implements the clone/checkout elsewhere.